# Is there an established name for this type of Operation and do efficient algorithms exist for it?

Tags: math, dataset, conditional-statements, operation

The original dataset constists of X,Y datapoints where each datapoint satisfies the condition that no other datapoint has both X and Y values lesser than its own.

The operation performed is to add a new datapoint to the dataset, and then remove any datapoints which no longer satisfy the condition above.

In the example below, the points in the blue region are removed from the original set because they no longer satisfy the condition.

[image: Dataset Operation]

Is there an established name for this type of operation, and if so, do any algorithms or libraries exist to perform this efficiently on the CPU or GPU?

Comment: What's the typical number of elements in one of your datasets ?

Comment: From 10 to 100 elements

Comment: In that case a quick loop through all the elements to find those in the forbidden zone will probably be as fast as anything else.  All the fancy spatial index structures will probably impose a significant overhead -- don't forget that an `O(k*n)` algorithm only outperforms an `O(c*n^2)` algorithm for certain values of the constants `k` and `c`.  As for doing the work on a GPU, unless the data is already on the GPU the memory-transfer time will almost certainly exceed the naive-computation time.

Comment: Thanks. Are you aware if this particular operation has a name?

Comment: No, I'm not aware of any name for it.

Comment: It's a two-dimensional range query (where the range itself is a halfspace or quarterspace).

Comment: The optimal algorithm would depend on the data structure that you are using to represent the data sets and whether or not the points are already sorted according to their x-coordinate. What programming language are you using and how are you storing the points?

Comment: Using C# and the points at sorted in a List

Comment: I agree with @HighPerformanceMark that a simple solution is probably the best here. However, this is actually a case of search of a [online convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) problem if you add a `(+infinity, +infinity)` vertex to your data, so you can actually add each point in `O(log n)` time, and probably can't do better (but `n` would need to be big for `O(n log n)` to become sensibly better than `O(n²)`, so you're probably better off with the simple solution).